My Javascript code is unable to detect Chrome's light/dark mode
Chrome Version: Version 130.0.6723.117 (Official Build) (arm64)
Mac OS Version: Sequoia version 15.1 (Apple Silicon)
I would like to be able to detect Chrome's light/dark mode as set in in Chrome's Settings.  I can imagine a case where the user has set their Mac OS Appearance setting to light and their Chrome Appearance Mode to dark (or vice versa).  In that situation, I would like to style my page according to the Chrome settings.
However, I'm unable to detect the user's Chrome Appearance Mode using the window.matchMedia approach.
Here is my code embedded in an HTML file:
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      const darkModeQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

      const isDarkMode = () => {
        return darkModeQuery.matches;
      }

      const toggleDarkMode = (isDarkMode) => {
        if (isDarkMode) {
          console.log("We're in Dark Mode");
        } else {
          console.log("We're in Light Mode");
        }
      }

      toggleDarkMode(isDarkMode());

      darkModeQuery.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        console.log("Detected Mode Change");
        toggleDarkMode(event.matches);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>

When I go to the Mac OS preferences and toggle between light and dark mode, my event listener gets called and the correct console message is logged:
Mac OS Appearance setting
However, when I go to the Chrome Settings, and toggle between light and dark mode, the event listener is not called:
Chrome Settings.  In addition to that, the isDarkMode function always returns my Mac OS Appearance setting and not Chrome's mode setting.
This accepted StackOverflow.com answer suggests that the above code should at least be able to detect the browser's mode.
If the window.matchMedia approach is not designed to detect the browser's mode, is there another way to detect the browser's mode?
When I set a breakpoint in the code in the browser's Dark Mode, I see the value of the darkModeQuery is the following: Debugger Tooltip where  darkModeQuery.matches is false.  I would expect it to be true.
I've tried serving this file from a locally running web server (e.g. python -m http.server) and just opening it from Finder with the same results.
I have read the MDN docs, tried the Gemini suggested code, and tried half a dozen stackoverflow.com questions but none of the solutions work for me.  Could there be some other factor at play here?
Thanks!
